# Mock REST, how to save binary file attachment from client request to file system?

Tags: rest, groovy, mocking, soapui

I have SOAPUI running mock REST and returing some json resonse, this part is working okay.

On the SoapUI server, I would like to save the binary file attachment from the client's REST request, which is coming from another client application not SOAPUI test request, to SOAPUI server side during processing of the client's request. Where do I start with this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research so far? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed stackoverflow help how-to and searched here and researched soapui community forum and tried few things like Soapui dump file option, but this is only for test request coming from soapui client. also tried groovy script to save raw request but again this is only works for soapui test case not request coming to soapui mock server from another app. I have posted question at soapui but not getting any response, so just trying here.